# trying to add replication to phpmyadmin but after adding user it it errors

Tags: phpmyadmin, mariadb

so I set up the primary server crap

```
server-id=3703097
log_bin=mysql-bin
log_error=mysql-bin.err
```

then was asked to make a replicate user. this is the code it tried to run

```sql
CREATE USER 'Replication'@'%' USING '***';GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'Replication'@'%' REQUIRE NONE;
```

but it returned an error that google couldn't get anything.

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'USING '*B1CFD2B84F03B7A8AD4C592954CC884799A445F0'' at line 1

what do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: `check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use`:  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-user/

Comment: Error messages, useful for reading. Not just a google search term generator.